# How can I group properties of different types in C#?

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, properties, pageobjects

In class DiamondListingPage : PageBase
I try to create one grouped enumerated property, which contains other objects with different types derived also from  PageBase.

Now I have singles properties, and I can't use foreach with it.

```
public class DiamondListingPage : PageBase
{
      public View3x3Tile View3x3Tile { get; set; } = MyPages.View3x3Tile;
      public CombTableView CombTableView { get; set; } = MyPages.CombTableView;
      public TableView TableView { get; set; } = MyPages.TableView;
}
```

Instead this three properties I want to use collection of them from other classes, like DiamondListingPage.SubpagesList.TableView instead the current DiamondListingPage.TableView. And I also want to use foreach for this new collection DiamondListingPage.SubpagesList.

View3x3Tile, CombTableView, TableView it are different classes derived from PageBase.

Comment: I think you will need to rephrase your question, because I don't understand what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: so, everything was okay till I decide to create foreach loop for properties in  DiamondListingPage. 

All classes have the same interface and override specific methods. I would to call this method for every aggregated subclass from DiamondListingPage.

public override void VerifyExpectedElementsAreDisplayed(){
foreach (subClass in subClassList){
 subClass.VerifyExpectedElementsAreDisplayed()
}

where subClass has type TableView : PageBase or CombTableView : PageBase and etc

Comment: I still don't understand. If you need a collection of properties you have to use reflection, but I don't think that that is what you actually want to do ...

Comment: I am not want to use reflections, because I also want to to collect only some specific properties for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have class with properties that you can access idividually, but also you want to access some of them grouped in form of a collection so you can use *foreach* on them.

You can use the [C# iterator method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt639331.aspx) to achieve that. Theese methods use *yield return* to return elements of the *IEnumerable*. So the code would look like this:

```
 public class DiamondListingPage : PageBase
 {
      public View3x3Tile View3x3Tile { get; set; } = MyPages.View3x3Tile;
      public CombTableView CombTableView { get; set; } = MyPages.CombTableView;
      public TableView TableView { get; set; } = MyPages.TableView;

      public IEnumerable<PageBase> SubPagesList() {
          yield return View3xTitle;
          yield return CombTableView;
          yield return TableView;
      }
 }
```

You can then access specific properties and iterate over them like this:

```
DiamondListingPage x = new DiamondListingPage();
x.View3xTitle = null // accessing individual property

foreach (PageBase p in x.SubPagesList()) {
    // do something with p
}
```

Also in *SubPagesList* method you can control which properties will be iterated over.